# Monero wallet code base dependencies and APIs?

Tags: api, wallet

I would like to know what dependencies the Monero wallet application for Linux or Android code base has, such as Chromium or Google APIs?  Is there a list of them somewhere without having to dig through the source code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For *compiling*, the dependencies are all listed in the project's [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#dependencies) file. When built as static binaries though (the way the releases are built), there are no runtime dependencies, but if you compiled as dynamic, the libraries listed as dependencies are then required to be installed on the target system.

For any Android/iOS wallets, you will need to consult with those particular projects.